(APHORISMES SUR LA SAGESSE DANS LA VIE, Arthur Schopenhauer), justification de « en»
Tiré de APHORISMES SUR LA SAGESSE DANS LA VIE, Arthur Schopenhauer, première traduction par J. A. Cantacuzène.

Voilà donc sur quoi repose l'excellente règle d'Aristote rapportée ci-dessus, d'avoir à diriger notre attention non sur les jouissances et les agréments de la vie, mais sur les
moyens d'échapper autant qu'il est possible aux maux innombrables dont elle est semée. Si cette voie n'était pas la vraie, l'aphorisme de Voltaire « Le bonheur n'est qu'un
rêve et la douleur est réelle », serait aussi faux qu'il est juste en réalité. Aussi, quand on veut arrêter le bilan de sa vie au point de vue eudémonologique, il ne faut pas établir son compte d'après les plaisirs qu'on a goûtés, mais d'après les maux auxquels on s'en soustrait.

eudémonologique : Relatif à l'eudémonologie, art du bonheur, s'appuyant sur ce que l'on est plus que ce que l'on a ou ce que l'on paraît.
« En » est clairement le pronom « en » ; « s'en soustraire » n'existe pas tel que par exemple, « s'en faire » en tant que forme verbale où « en » n'a pas de rôle grammatical, ce qui signifie que l'on reconnait que « en » doit avoir un antécédent.
Je n'ai aucun problème en rapport avec la phrase modifiée suivante.

Aussi, quand on veut arrêter le bilan de sa vie au point de vue eudémonologique, il ne faut pas établir son compte d'après les plaisirs qu'on a goûtés, mais d'après les maux auxquels on s'est soustrait.

D'un côté on a « les plaisir qu'on a goutés » et de l'autre, « les mots auxquels on s'est soustrait »; « que » se justifie parce qu'on goute qqch (transitif), et « auxquels » se justifie parce qu'on se soustrait à qqch (intransitif). De plus l'addition de « est » donne du sens à La phrase, puisque un bilan arrêté implique les maux auxquels on s'est soustrait et pas ceux auxquels on se soustrait, c'est à dire pas ceux auxquels on peut continuer à se soustraire.
S'il n'y a pas d'erreur de typographie, comment doit-on comprendre cette phrase ? Quel est l'antécédent de ce pronom ?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
